# Why is my code gitting slower in Read-only mode in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, performance, optimization, openpyxl

I have a class-function 'loadxl()', which reads data from Excel to Python using openpyxl. I've tried to make it faster by using "read-only" mode and inbuilt iterators, but my attempt to optimize the function turned out to be half as fast as the original code.

The data I'm reading are structured in a 9241 X 14 matrix. I'm using the data to initialize variables in my class 'Case', which are mostly 'numpy' arrays.

In my initial code, I didn't use a 'read_only' workbook, and I used the 'sheet.cell()' method to access the cells. This is my original code:

```
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as opyxl

class Case:
    def __init__(
    self, filepath = None
    ):

       #Bus data
       self.sbase = 500 #Default MVA value
       self.numbus = np.empty(0, dtype = np.int32)
       self.slackbusnr = []
       self.busname = np.empty(0, dtype = np.str)
       self.buscod = np.empty(0, dtype = np.int32)
       self.basekv = np.empty(0, dtype = np.double)
       self.gs = np.empty(0, dtype = np.double)
       self.bs = np.empty(0, dtype = np.double)
       self.area = np.empty(0, dtype = np.int32)
       self.zone = np.empty(0, dtype = np.int32)
       self.nbuses = 0
       self.vomag = np.empty(0, dtype = np.double)
       self.voang = np.empty(0, dtype = np.double)

    def loadxl(self,filename):       
       wb = opyxl.load_workbook(filename)
       bus = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Bus-data')
       i = 1
       while (bus.cell(row = i,column = 1).value is not None):

            self.numbus = np.append(self.numbus,int(bus.cell(row = i, column = 1).value))
            if(int(bus.cell(row = i, column = 3).value) == 3):
                self.slackbusnr = self.nbuses
            self.buscod = np.append(self.buscod, int(bus.cell(row = i, column = 4).value))
            self.pload = np.append(self.pload, float(bus.cell(row = i, column = 5 ).value)/self.sbase)
            self.qload = np.append( self.qload, float(bus.cell(row = i, column = 6).value)/self.sbase)
            self.gs = np.append(self.gs, float(bus.cell(row = i, column = 7).value)/self.sbase)
            self.bs = np.append(self.bs, float(bus.cell(row = i, column = 8).value)/self.sbase)
            self.area = np.append(self.area,int(bus.cell(row = i, column = 9).value))
            self.vomag = np.append(self.vomag, float(bus.cell(row = i, column = 10).value))
            self.voang = np.append(self.voang, float(bus.cell(row = i, column = 11).value)/180*math.pi)
            self.basekv  = np.append(self.basekv,float(bus.cell(row = i, column = 12).value))        
            self.zone = np.append(self.zone,int(bus.cell(row = i, column = 13).value))
            self.nbuses += 1
            i+=1
```

The original code uses approx 10s to read the data. After reading the docs of openpyxl, and a bunch of posts online, I realized I could optimize the code by loading a 'read_only' workbook instead. However, the '.cell()' method is extremely slow in the Read-only-mode, so I used 'ws.iter_rows()' instead of the while-loop. The new code is as follows:

```
def loadxl2(filename): 

   wb = opyxl.load_workbook(filename, read_only = True)
                    bus = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Bus-data')
   for row in bus.iter_rows(min_col = 1, min_row = 1, values_only = True):
                if(row[0] == None):
                    break
                self.numbus = np.append(self.numbus,int(row[0]))
                self.busname = np.append(self.busname, str(row[1]))
                self.buscod = np.append(self.buscod, int(row[2]))
                if(int(row[2]) == 3):
                    self.slackbusnr = self.nbuses
                self.pload = np.append(self.pload, float(row[ 3])/self.sbase)
                self.qload = np.append( self.qload, float(row[4])/self.sbase)
                self.gs = np.append(self.gs, float(row[5])/self.sbase)
                self.bs = np.append(self.bs, float(row[6])/self.sbase)
                self.area = np.append(self.area,float(row[7]))
                self.vomag = np.append(self.vomag, float(row[8]))
                self.voang = np.append(self.voang, float(row[9])/180*math.pi)
                self.basekv  = np.append(self.basekv,float(row[10]))        
                self.zone = np.append(self.zone,float(row[11]))
                self.nbuses += 1
```

The problem is: the new code is about half as fasts as the original!

I've been using 'line_profile' on the two codes, and found that even tho loading the workbook with 'wb.load_workbook(read_only = True)' is much faster, the for-loop in the new code is 60X slower than the while-loop. (the appending of the data inside the two loops show equal performance).

The openpyxl docs, and online blogs/posts has said that reading data should be faster in Read-only-mode and by using inbuilt iterators, so does anyone know what might be the issue with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you use `self.numbus` meaning you are using classes and we can't see your whole code.

A sure fire way to slow down pyautogui is to open workbook many times. So you might want to check if you open your workbook only once.

Another thing is that I can't see what `np` is. Can you add more of your code?

Since you're working with classes, I wonder if you load up everything in memory. That might slow it down a little as well.

I had a similar project and I wrote column by column, that wasn't a great idea either. It got really slow. Then I'd opened another workbook to write the data to. Basically creating a copy of the workbook in memory. Then I wrote that once to the file. 
So basically: Look at the amount of write operations to your file and decrease that.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I've added the class now. I'm sure that I'm only loading the workbook once.

Answer (score 0):

When you say slow? What do you mean by slow? How many seconds, minutes or hours?

This is a small file for Excel so times will probably be mainly determined by loading the libraries. That said, you are also performing the same operations on the same columns each time. Probably makes sense to let numpy do all operations on the elements in the arrays at once. This is, after all, the main point of vector operations.